# Format String into Multiple Values - Separate by Comma - SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, substring

I've this values in a column value named `[T] (varchar(100))`:

```
AS00516003,QD00516009,XD00516089
```

How can I get the following string in order to get the results into **IN** statement:

```
'AS00516003','QD00516009','XD00516089'
```

Because If I do this query with the first value I don't get any values:

```
  SELECT *
  FROM [dbo].[TABLE]
  WHERE [NUMBER] IN (SELECT  [T]  FROM [dbo].[TEST])
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I split a string so I can access item x?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647/how-do-i-split-a-string-so-i-can-access-item-x)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need dynamic SQL in order to achieve that:

```
declare @query varchar(4000)
set @query = 'select * from [dbo].[table] where [number] in ('
--here you will append results from [T] table, all values stored in this table
--will be in the list in WHERE clause of dynamic query
select @query += '''' + REPLACE([T], ',', ''',''') + ''',' from [dbo].[TEST]
--remove last comma and close list with )
set @query = LEFT(@query, len(@query) - 1) + ')'

exec(@query)
```

Answer (score 0):

You might use String_Split, like this:

```
SELECT [T]
FROM YourTable
CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(Tags, ',');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this below script

```
DECLARE @val nvarchar(max)='AS00516003,QD00516009,XD00516089'
,@ReqFormat nvarchar(max)

DECLARE @temp TABLE (Data nvarchar(100))
INSERT INTO @temp
SELECT @val
SELECT * FROM @temp

;WITH CTE
AS
(
SELECT ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 1 )) AS Id
    ,''''+Split.a.value('.','nvarchar(100)')+'''' AS Data
FROM
(
SELECT  CAST('<S>'+REPLACE(Data,',','</S><S>')+'</S>' AS XML)Data from @temp
)AS A
CROSS APPLY Data.nodes('S') AS Split(a)
)
SELECT @ReqFormat=STUFF((SELECT ', '+Data  FROM CTE
FOR XML PATH ('')),1,1,'')

SELECT @ReqFormat AS ReqFormat
```

Result

```
GivenData
-----------------------------------
AS00516003,QD00516009,XD00516089

ReqFormat
----------------------------------------
'AS00516003', 'QD00516009', 'XD00516089'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make script as user defined function like below

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf_GetUnsplitData]
(
@string nvarchar(max)
)
RETURNS  @OutTable TABLE
(
DATA nvarchar(max)
)
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @Temp AS TABLE
    (
    DATA nvarchar(max)
    )
    INSERT INTO @Temp
    SELECT @string

    DECLARE @OutTableInternal AS TABLE
    (
    DATA nvarchar(max)
    )

    INSERT INTO @OutTableInternal(DATA)
    SELECT 
     ''''+Split.a.value('.','nvarchar(1000)')+'''' As DATA
    FROM
    (
    SELECT 
    CAST('<S>'+REPLACE(DATA,',','</S><S>')+'</S>' AS XML ) AS DATA
    FROM @Temp
    )A
    CROSS APPLY DATA.nodes('S') AS Split(a)

    INSERT INTO @OutTable(DATA)
    SELECT STUFF((SELECT ', '+DATA FROM @OutTableInternal
    FOR XML PATH ('')),1,1,'')


RETURN
END

SELECT * FROM [dbo].[udf_GetUnsplitData] (
   'AS00516003,QD00516009,XD00516089')
GO
```

Result

```
DATA
---------------------------------------
'AS00516003', 'QD00516009', 'XD00516089'
```